# How to remove files starting with double hyphen?

Tags: bash, unix, filenames

I have some files on my Unix machine that start with

```
 --
```

e.g. `--testings.html`

If I try to remove it I get the following error:

```
cb0$ rm --testings.html
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

I tried

```
rm "--testings.html" || rm '--testings.html'
```

but nothing works.

**How can I remove such files on terminal?**

Comment: Same on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47003/deleting-a-unix-directory-with-a-hyphen-in-the-name) and [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus).

Comment: @Dorian Well ok, but I was first :)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
rm -- --testings.html
```

The `--` option tells rm to treat all further arguments as file names, not as options, even if they start with `-`.

This isn't particular to the rm command. The getopt function implements it, and many (all?) UNIX-style commands treat it the same way: `--` terminates option processing, and anything after it is a regular argument.

http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt

Comment: This is not standard across all versions of Unix, though it does work on most. See vatine's answer for an alternative that works with all versions.

Answer (score 56):

```
rm -- --somefile
```

While that works, it's a solution that relies on `rm` using getopts for parsing its options.  There are applications out there that do their own parsing and will puke on that too (because they might not necessarily implement the "`--` means end of options" logic).

Because of that, the solution you should drive through your skull is this one:

```
rm ./--somefile
```

It will always work, because this way your arguments never begin with a `-`.

Moreover, if you're trying to make really decent shell scripts; you should technically be putting `./` in front of all your filename parameter expansions to prevent your scripts from breaking due to funky filename input (or to prevent them being abused/exploited to do things they're not supposed to do:  for instance, `rm` will delete files but skip over directories; while `rm -rf *` will delete everything.  Passing a filename of "`-rf`" to a script or somebody `touch ~victim/-rf`'ing could in this way be used to change its behaviour with really bad consequences).

Comment: +1 because you're right, but making scripts bulletproof is a whole other issue besides dealing with one awkward filename. If the question was "how do I removed files starting with hyphens or containing spaces, ;, <>, $, and other malicious junk" then it would need the full answer :-)

Answer (score 18):

Either `rm -- --testings.html` or `rm ./--testings.html`.

Answer (score 7):

```
rm -- --testings.html
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to do it is to use  find ... -name "--*" -delete

```
touch -- --file 
find -x . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "--*" -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

For a more generalised approach for deleting files with impossible characters in the filename, one option is to use the inode of the file.

It can be obtained via `ls -i`.

e.g.

```
$ ls -lai | grep -i test
452998712 -rw-r--r--  1 dim   dim      6 2009-05-22 21:50 --testings.html
```

And to erase it, with the help of find:

```
$ find ./ -inum 452998712 -exec rm \{\} \;
```

This process can be beneficial when dealing with lots of files with filename peculiarities, as it can be easily scripted.

Comment: That works only because it invokes `rm` with the argument `./--testings.html`. It's easier just to type `rm ./--testings.html` directly -- which also doesn't need to traverse the entire directory tree. (You could avoid the latter by using `-maxdepth 1`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
rm ./--testings.html
```

or

```
rm -- --testings.html
```