# Removing files called --exclude=*.xdr

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Somehow I must have mistyped a command, because now I have files named --exclude=*.xdr and --exclude=*.h5 in one of my directories. I want to delete them. Only problem is whenever I do something like:

```
rm --exclude=*.xdr
```

it thinks I'm passing an argument to the rm command. I've tried encasing in single and double quotes but it still didn't work. How can I delete these files?

Cheers

Comment: `rm -- --exclude=*.xdr`  the rm man page will tell you what -- does

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove files starting with double hyphen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen)

Comment: first tell us how did you create it?

Comment: Not sure, I think I was trying to tarball a directory but obviously did a typo or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag interpretation is done based purely on text. Any string that doesn't start with a `-` is not a flag. The path to a file in the local directory can start with `./` (the `.` means "current directory").

I'd also recommend reading the man page for `rm`, as that explicitly lists two different ways of doing exactly this.

- `rm -- --blah`
- `rm ./--blah`

Answer (score 1):

```
 rm -- "--exclude=.xdr"
```

Use this command for delete that file

Answer (score 0):

What about using find:

```
find . -type f -name "--exclude*" -exec rm {} \; -print
```