# osx find exec rm find: exec: unknown primary or operator

Tags: bash, unix, find, rm

I've got a bunch of files that end in "-e" that I want to remove.

```
$ find . -name "*-e" exec rm {} \;
find: exec: unknown primary or operator
```

Is the regex expanding in some way that messes everything up?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen), though nothing special is needed since `{}` will expand to `./some/path/-e` which can not be treated as an option.

Comment: I stumbled on this question as I was looking for example uses of `find` and `exec`, overlooking the fact that you were doing a `rm`! PSA: **This command will delete the contents of a directory! Use with caution if you're just hacking around.** I learned the hard way.

Comment: I was forgetting to use quotes around my `-name` argument value. The `*` was getting expanded by the shell and not by `find`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It should be:

```
find . -name "*-e" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Or better:

```
find . -name "*-e" -exec rm '{}' +
```

As per `man find`:

```
-exec utility [argument ...] {} +
   Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for 
   each invocation of utility. This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1).
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error for both of these. :(

Comment: Me too: $ find . -name *.m4
find: ad.m4: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @dba.in.ua: What is output of `type find` on your shell?

Comment: For this issue with a find query like `find ~ -iname "*.py"`, I only need to quote the filename sequence for this to work. The `{}` doesn't need to be quoted when I run it

Answer (score 15):

+1 to @anubhava's answer.  However, I did have to be very careful before it worked:

## TLDR:  the format is  `-exec <your-command> {} \;`

### Hint: use something harmless, like `echo` to get it working first.

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec echo {} \;`

```
./081.documentation/000.sticky.list_url_info_markdown/worklocal.sh
./081.documentation/001.fixed.p2.collab_diagrams/common.sh
./081.documentation/001.fixed.p2.collab_diagrams/worklocal.sh
```

Once it works you can get all fancy with extra find options as in

`find . -name "*.sh" -maxdepth 3 -exec echo {} \;`

### Be sure to use `-exec`, not `--exec` or `exec`

remember that find’s options all take 1 dash.  `-exec` is no different.

`find . -name "*.sh" --exec echo {} \;`

❌ `find: --exec: unknown primary or operator`

`find . -name "*.sh" exec echo {} \;`

❌ `find: exec: unknown primary or operator`

Notice how what comes after **find:** reflects what you put in? Here find has no idea what’s going on so you get a generic *I don't know* message.

### Once you are using `-exec` terminate with  `\;` - that space is critical

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec echo {}\;`

❌ `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`
................. you want to see `-exec` in your error message. that part is good ✅ find knows what it is looking at so it has `-exec` related messages.

### Finally, replace `echo` with your actual payload:

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec reformat.py --myfancy-option-to-reformat {} \;`

### '{}' vs {} made no difference whatsoever.

It might, under some conditions, maybe if your paths have spaces in them so if you’re unsure put the quotes.  But I couldn't trigger any errors even with spaces and with different commands (cat, ls) than echo.

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec echo {} \;`

```
./bar zoom.sh
./foo.sh
./worklocal.sh
```

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec echo '{}' \;`

```
./bar zoom.sh
./foo.sh
./worklocal.sh
```

I'm not saying the quotes are useless, I am saying they're not causing *unknown primary or operator*.

### ending with  `+` strips newlines between invocations:

Don't forget that space before the +.

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec echo {} +`

```
./bar zoom.sh ./foo.sh ./worklocal.sh
```

Yes,  I dream of a more user-friendly find. But macos's Spotlight-related [mdfind is, by light-years, even more unfriendly when it comes to options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350773/limiting-mdfind-on-terminal-to-files-changed-in-the-last-x-minutes-hours)

Answer (score 3):

use find delete args:

```
find ./ -name "*-e" -delete
```

Answer (score -3):

just use: `find . "*-e" -type f exec rm '{}' +`
it works with Mac OSX find version

Comment: it doesn't  `-exec`, not `exec`, is needed.