# How to replicate VSCode's 'search and replace' code in Bash?

Tags: macos, sed

I have a project that contains one file `a.txt` that contains the text `hello`, and a folder called `b` that contains a file `c.txt` that also contains the text `hello`. I want to run a bash command that will replace these two instances of `hello` with `goodbye`, identical to VSCode's search-and-replace functionality.

I've tried `sed -i '.bak' 's/hello/goodbye/g' *`, but it gives me the error `sed: folder: in-place editing only works for regular files`.

How should I approach this? I'm using MacOS.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `*` matches something more than the files you told us about, probably a directory. Voting to close as unreproducible / general computing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` to locate the files you need to edit and the `--exec` param to run your `sed` command.  Something like

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sed -i '.bak' 's/hello/goodbye/g' {} \;
```

Comment: When I run that I get `find: --exec: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Sorry I should mention I'm using a Mac. I've updated the original question.

Comment: should be -exec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915657/osx-find-exec-rm-find-exec-unknown-primary-or-operator

Comment: It does do the replacements, but it shows the following two outputs: `sed: .: in-place editing only works for regular files` and `sed: ./folder: in-place editing only works for regular files`, and it then creates the .bak backup files for each file. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: The idea here is correct, but the code is wrong; it's missing a `-name` predicate before the wildcard `'*.txt'`. Probably add `-type f` before, or instead, depending on what you really need.