# Linux,How to delete a file named "-C"

Tags: linux, command

I have a file named "-C". How can I delete it? This doesn't work:

```
rm -rf -C
```

I guess I need to use escape characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove files starting with double hyphen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen)

Answer (score 2):

```
rm ./-C
```

That should do it, given you're in the correct directory.

Answer (score 2):

you can use '--' to delimit the option list.

```
touch -- -aname # will create '-aname' file  
rm -- -aname # will delete it
```

more details in coreutils info pages.

Answer (score 0):

<s>either

`rm -rf "-C"`

or</s>  
`rm -rf ./-C`

Comment: rm -rf ./-C  is working,thanks

Comment: No need for the -r option (it being a single file).

Comment: The  double quotes are not going to help; it's not the shell which is parsing the options.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't have linux nearby to try out.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try escaping the "-" character?

rm -rf "\-C"