# How to remove file with special characters?

Tags: linux, unix, non-ascii-characters

I have a weird file on a Unix filesystem. It seems to have some special characters in the file name, but I've not been able to remove it. Even if I don't write the name directly in the `rm` command (and I do `ls | rm` instead), I get an error that the file doesn't exist. Below some commands that I've tried after a few searches on the internet, in order to debug the issue.

Do you have any suggestions on how to remove it? The system is AIX 7.1. I've tried with `rm` and a `perl` script too (simply listing all files and deleting everything from the folder), and none worked. I can't move the folder to `/tmp` either, I get the same error.

Thanks!

```
[root@server] ls -1b | od -bc
0000000  342 134 062 060 060 134 062 062 063 012
           ▒   \   2   0   0   \   2   2   3  \n
0000012
[root@server]$ ls -li
ls: 0653-341 The file ./– does not exist.
total 0
[root@server]$ ls
–
[root@server]$ ls | od -bc
0000000  342 200 223 012
           ▒ 200 223  \n
0000004
[root@server]$ rm *
rm: –: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

***Screenshot***

[image: rm failure]

Comment: Not the most insightful solution, but did you try to remove the file via a (gui) filemanager?

Comment: With bash/Aix this works for me: `/bin/touch $'\342'; ls -l $'\342'; /bin/rm $'\342'; ls -l $'\342'` Mind you, it is not clear that you have Linux or Aix.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the following and unfortunately it doesn't work. I have AIX as it's written in the question.

    [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342\200\223';
    ls: 0653-341 The file – does not exist.
    [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342\200\223\012';
    ls: 0653-341 The file –
     does not exist.
    [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342\200\223\012';
    [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342''\200''\223''\012';
    ls: 0653-341 The file ▒\200\223\012 does not exist.
    [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342''\200''\223';
    ls: 0653-341 The file ▒\200\223 does not exist.

Comment: [root@server]$ ls -l $'\342\200\223';
    ls: 0653-341 The file – does not exist.
    [root@server]$ rm $'\342\200\223';
    rm: –: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean _a weird file on a linux hdd_?

Comment: Please qoute the output of this: `echo * | od -bc`

Comment: 0000000  342 200 223 012
           ▒ 200 223  \n
0000004

Comment: @filip: Don't comment your own question. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52438836/edit) your question to improve it (and that is needed). Dont give screenshots but just commands and outputs (on StackOverflow, you need four spaces in front of each line to render them)

Comment: I could create such a file with this command: `LC_ALL=C touch $(printf '\342\200\223')` and delete it with this: `LC_ALL=C rm $(printf '\342\200\223')`

Comment: It would be nice to explain how did you came into such a mess: is it a joke from a friend, did you have some program so buggy to the point of creating such filenames, etc... Do you care that much about the directory containing that weird file?

Comment: If a directory contains one useless weird file, why can't you remove that directory entirely?

Comment: It doesn't let me. the "rm" command fails like I wrote in the description, even if I try it recursively on the directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove files starting with double hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706196/608639)

Answer (score 29):

A relatively safe way would be to list files' [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) with `ls -i` and then delete the one you need with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -inum $inum -delete` (`$inum` is the inode to delete).

And be grateful you are on Unix! ❤

Comment: Are you sure that `-inum` is in POSIX `find`? I don't know!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I checked on Linux, Cygwin, and Solaris, so the odds are good.

Comment: @flip - as a next experiment I would try a small C program and the debugger, if you still need to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I managed to try the delete by inode using "find . -inum $inode -exec rm {} \;"  and find says that the file "status" is invalid, whatever that means.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I somehow managed to create a file that began with a newline character, and this was the only way to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Your file name contains a en-dash `–`; that is not the hyphen-minus sign `-` (unicode [U+002D HYPHEN MINUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm), also in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)), but [U+2013 EN DASH](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Maybe your file name contains other weird characters (then you need to find which ones).

Try first to list that file, without [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), using the [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) *command* (read about [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)...). Consider also using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on that `ls` command. Try also `echo * | od -cxi` to understand what globbing is done. This means some `ls ./–` (or something similar). I am supposing it works (perhaps some [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) is needed). Find exactly how to have `ls ./– | od -cxi` work correctly. Then use `ls -l` instead of just `ls` to be sure (sometimes, `ls` might be [aliased](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases), so you need to disable that, perhaps by typing `/bin/ls` instead of `ls`)

You could remove it by copy/pasting that weird name, or, after changing appropriately your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) with [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)), perhaps with

```
rm ./–
```

the last character of that command ([copy/paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste)d) is the Unicode U+2013 EN DASH; How to enter exactly that en-dash Unicode character is a different story (it could depend upon your desktop environment, your terminal emulator, your window manager, your keyboard layout, your localization). On Linux desktops, the `charmap` GUI utility (from Debian or Ubuntu package `gucharmap`) could help. You can select that character with your mouse (amongst thousands of other unicode characters) and copy/paste it in UTF-8.

If your directory has a few entries, you might try

```
  rm -rif .
```

and the `/bin/rm` command will prompt you for every entry (or try just `rm -if *` if you don't want to descend in sub-directories).

If the naughty file is the only one in its directory (excluding of course the `.` and `..` entries; check with `ls -al`), you could `rm -rf` that directory and recreate that directory with `mkdir`

If your shell is nicely configured to [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) on Unicode characters (not just on bytes or ASCII) you might try `rm -i ./?`

If nothing else works, you could even write a small C program calling [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) or [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) (and checking that it has succeeded) on `"\342\200\223"` (the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding of the en-dash). If you need to scan programmatically your weird directory (to find the *exact* weird name), consider [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), or [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), loop on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) etc... Or code that in a scripting language such as Python. And you could use some GUI file manager doing the same.

In 2018, we have [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). If by mistake your desktop and localization is not using UTF-8, you need to correct that. See [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html).

You might also use the [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) command to get that weird character (that `printf` command [is](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/printf/) in POSIX). So the command `rm -v $(printf "\342\200\223")` should work (on AIX, `rm` might not be the GNU one, so you cannot use `rm -v` only `rm`)

Comment: I tried : rm ./–
rm: ./–: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: I also tried: [root@server]$ rm $(printf "\342\200\223")
rm: –: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: So, you were not in the right directory containing that file. You should change it using `cd`

Comment: Then the filename you gave us is not the right one. Ensure that some `ls ./–` works correctly. Perhaps there are other characters, or perhaps you need some shell quotation

Comment: The file that I gave you is the correct one.

Comment: rm -if . deleted everything in folder (-f force flag) so omit -f and it should work ?!.

Comment: Do NOT execute `rm -if *` if you only want to delete one or some files. Option `-f` overrides any previous `-i` options, deleting all files in the directory without confirmation (at least on my system).