# How to delete folders that start with "--" through command line

Tags: linux, command-line

After running a bad command my computer generates folders that start with "--". When I run `ls` I get something like:

```
   workspace
   --workspace
```

I don't know how to delete these folders through the command line.

`rm -r --workspace` does not work. I only have access to this machine through CLI so I can't delete them using the gui.

My OS is Linux 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove files starting with double hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove file with special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52438836/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `rm` to stop parsing and use your arguments verbatim. You do this by passing a final `--` argument before the file or folder name.

```
rm -r -- --workspace
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly :)